what is the meaning when a makefile rule has prerequisites but without the recipe?
INSTALL = /usr/local/bin/install -c
INSTALLDATA = /usr/local/bin/install -c -m 644
# The directory to install tar in.
bindir = $(prefix)/bin
# The directory to install the info files in.
infodir = $(prefix)/info




.PHONY: all
all:    tar rmt tar.info

tar:    $(OBJS)
        $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $(OBJS) $(LIBS)

rmt:    rmt.c
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ rmt.c

tar.info: tar.texinfo
        makeinfo tar.texinfo




.PHONY: install
install: all
        $(INSTALL) tar $(bindir)/$(binprefix)tar
        -test ! -f rmt || $(INSTALL) rmt /etc/rmt
        $(INSTALLDATA) $(srcdir)/tar.info* $(infodir)

I cannot understand the rule for the target 'all', it doesnot have a recipe, so when typing 'make all', what would happen and what if when without the line '.PHONY:all'.

The all target simply depends on the tar, rmt, and tar.info targets, but doesn't do anything except making sure those three are built.
.PHONY is an extension that means the phony targets all and install here don't correspond to actual files. If the rule wasn't marked as phony, creating a file called all or install might cause the corresponding rules not to run.

No,Actually, in this case, '.PHONY:all' has no effect.

Cause there is no recipe for 'all', so even without declaring as PHONY, things can also work well.

@lcWhhx As ilkkachu said, if all is not a .PHONY target, creating a file called all would prevent the dependencies of all from being considered.

@Kusalananda, no, you can have a test

@lcWhhx I suggest you read the documentation that the answer refers to, especially the text around the sentence saying "In this example, the clean target will not work properly if a file named clean is ever created in this directory."

@Kusalananda What you said is specific to the case that the target has no prerequisites.

@lcWhhx There are examples of phony targets that have prerequisites further down in the text.
